# how does rpm uninstall a rpm in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, rpm

For which specific file rpm search first when any one fire command 
***rpm -e package_name***

Comment: Are you asking what order the files are removed in?

Comment: i wanted to know how rpm processes to uninstall a package? in which order it calls files and which of files sets are called first? would be happy if someone explains where does rpm stores information about particular package??

Comment: It uninstalls a package by removing all the package's files and running any scripts the package says to run at uninstall time. I still don't understand what you are trying to find out. The rpm databases live in `/var/lib/rpm` but they aren't going to help you much on their own.

Answer (score 0):

Check the package name using,

```
rpm -q package_name
```

you will find out which packages getting removed.